# Multiple Criteria and Multiple Returns Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

It's been a while since I've been here.  I've been struggling with a formula on Excel using multiple lookups giving multiple returns.
In this sheet, the inputs are: 
Location, Subject, Level.

I used the following formula to return the teacher's name in H4: 
=INDEX(D2:D26, MATCH(1, (H1=A2:A26)*(H2=B2:B26)*(H3=C2:C26), 0))

I'm trying to have it return the multiple student IDs.
With the following inputs: 
Location Lookup:    U

Subject Lookup: QC

Level Lookup:   2

I'm expecting the following student IDs being returned, but I'm not sure of how to solve this.
1012, 1013, 1014, 1015, 1016, 1017, 1018
!
'[image: Excel Image]

Can you please help??

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula in `H5` cell to get student IDs and fill down as you need.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$26,SMALL(IF(($A$1:$A$26=$H$1)*($B$1:$B$26=$H$2)*($C$1:$C$26=$H$3),ROW($D$1:$D$26)),ROWS($A$1:$A1))),"")
```

**As it is a array formula, Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.**

Comment: Yes!  That did the tick!  Would it matter if the Student IDs were on a different sheet?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be matter. It will also work fine. Just refer sheet name.